# Modify Orchard CMS search results

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Is it possible to modify the search results of Orchard, not to display parts (image gallery and contact form).

I created a site, added an image gallery. When doing searches the image gallery is displayed within the search results. The same with contact forms, they are also displayed in the search results.

Comment: You should read about placement.

Comment: Teach a man to fish; and you have fed him for a lifetime ...

Thanks!

Added "<Place Parts_ContactForm="-"/>" to my placement.info (in Orchard.Search folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added Place Parts_ContactForm="-"/ to my placement.info (in Orchard.Search folder). See http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info#OverridingPlacement

Answer (score 0):

In /Admin/ContentTypes, Edit the content type (ex : contact form), then uncheck the checkbox 'Index this content type for the search'

Comment: I'm having this same issue - what about excluding a single page (i.e. a thank you page for a form) from the search results?

Comment: The checkbox for "Contact Form Widget" is unchecked. I will read about placements.